# Margins/space between images won't work

Tags: html, css, image, margins

So I decided to add a new section to a gallery on my art page.  I thought I could just copy the CSS from the original and make a second "infobox" and "gallery" but the second set doesn't seem to acknowledge the "margin" code and instead, the images overlap slightly or appear crammed next to each other.

On this page: http://koneko-ealain.com/art.html  the bottom two images don't have the margin or the padding the top ones do, yet they remain slightly separated.  While on http://koneko-ealain.com/misc.html, the bottom two overlap slightly, also ignoring the codes for margins and padding.  I've copied what I assume will be pertinent to my issue as the sidebar has not caused me any trouble on any of the pages.

```
/*Infobox*/
#infobox{
width: 900px;
height: 500px;
clear: left;
background-color: none;
padding: 30px;
margin-left: 400px;
position: relative;
}
div > img{
width: 500px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
#infobox > p{
color: #000;
font-family: "Book Antiqua", Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-color: #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 0px; }
#copy{
opacity: .25;
font-size: 11px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
/*buttons*/
span > a > img{
height: 50px;
opacity: .25;
margin-left: 8px;
}
/*lightbox*/ div #gallery > a > img{
border-radius: 2px;
margin:5px;
} #infobox 2 > p{
color: #000;
font-family: "Book Antiqua", Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-color: #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 0px; }
}
/*lightbox*/ div #gallery 2> a > img{
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 5px;
} </style>
```

Comment: Jsfiddle is better than link to site.

Comment: `<div id="infobox 2">`, `<div id="gallery 2">` – those are not _valid_ ids.

Comment: What could be better IDs?  I wanted to make a separate gallery/section on the same page, but my first attempt resulted in the "commissioned works" image going waaaay off to the right for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how this will affect the rest of your site, but somewhere there is a style definition `div > a > img` that has a `margin-left -10px`. That would cause the problem.

To debug CSS problems you can use the following in Firefox:

*Firefox > Web Developer > Inspector*

Then click on any element on the page and it will show you the CSS and what causes what.

Comment: For some reason attempting to remove the negative margin results in both notepad & compozer failing to save the file.  Sadly I don't understand really any of what the web developer is telling me as far as errors other than it found 19 of them.

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping is caused by the following css:

```
div > a > img {
    margin-left: -10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Ditch that negative margin and it'll work. If you're trying to position images, you'll have more luck if you make the containing anchors `display: block` and float them, or use `display: inline-block` which has a few gotchas.